# Building a new extension in TYPO3

Tags: extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I am new to TYPO3. I am planning to build an extension that displays events in a month, year, week and day.My question is, how can I display the calendar in the frontend so that I can use my extension? Or shall I want to make a calendar and display in my own extension?

Can anyone help regarding this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: your question is a bit confusing, do you know the [extension builder](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder) ?  if you know german there are some nice tutorials ... [first](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CISH8lD8GtA) from three from PanadeEdu

Comment: anyhow if you are new I see lots of difficulties ... you'd probably start from the extension cal and then add your own extension to keep track of stuff you want to add ...

Comment: Suppose that I am building an extension using extension builder to display events in a month. How can I display a calendar in frontend for displaying the events? By the comment you had given, Shall I use cal extension? Or is there any other way to display calendar in frontend from my extension itself?

Comment: did you take it further ? I would not use cal but integrate the `tinyDatPicker library` to output my calendar in the frontend ... have a look at my answer below

Comment: did you do anything with the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the **[EXT:extension builder](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder)** to control the information for the calendar in typo3 and than add the functionality of a package like this **[tinyDatePicker](http://www.dematte.at/tinyDatePicker/)** to make my own calendar ... ( I never used the extension cal, please check that out first, it might have all the functionality you need )

I retain that its a handful for a beginner though, 
If you speak german ***Florian Tatzel*** made a very nice and comprehensive introduction to the extensionbuilder:

[TYPO3 6.1 Extbase Entwicklung - #1 Einführung](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CISH8lD8GtA)

[TYPO3 6.1 Extbase Entwicklung - #2 Ein einfaches Plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R257s37plKI)

[TYPO3 6.1 Extbase Entwicklung - #3 Datenbank, Model und Controller](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qw8oI4nzjew)

you can download his example extension **[here](https://github.com/PanadeEdu/pde_car_example)** (the link in youtube is stale)